# bibliografy .bst abbreviation in different languages

Tags: bibtex, languages

There are two BST files, one of which forms the sequesnce of names in the reference list, and the other makes correct abbreviations in different languages. However, I need only the first author.

Here only one author is given:

```
FUNCTION {format.names}
{
  #1 "{vv~}{ll}{~jj}{,~ff}" format.name$
}
```

Here we get several authors but the abbreviation given for different languages is correct:

```
FUNCTION {format.names}
{ 's :=
  #1 'nameptr :=
  s num.names$ 'numnames :=
  numnames 'namesleft :=
    { namesleft #0 > }
    {  s nameptr
       curlanguage "ukrainian" = curlanguage "russian" = or
       { "{vv~}{ll}{~jj}{~ff}" format.name$ 't := }
       { curlanguage "english" =
         { "{vv~}{ll}{~jj}{~f.}" format.name$ 't := }
         { "language is not defined: " language  "{vv~}{ll}{~jj}{~ff}" * * warning$ "{vv~}{ll}{~jj}{~ff}" }
        if$}
      if$
      nameptr #1 >
        {
          nameptr #4 =
          numnames #3 > and
            { "others" 't :=
              #1 'namesleft := }
            'skip$
          if$
          namesleft #1 >
            { ", " * t * }
            {
              t "others" =
              t "~others" =
              or
                { " " * bbl.etal * }
                { ", " * t * }
              if$
            }
          if$
        }
        't
      if$
      nameptr #1 + 'nameptr :=
      namesleft #1 - 'namesleft :=
    }
  while$
}
```

How to get only one autor in `format.names` depend on language?

Comment: What is the question? Please advise.

Comment: I want to get only one autor in `format.names` with selection of abbreviations depend on language.